# ListView Scrolls to Top when EditText Grows

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I have a `Listview` with `EditTexts` in every cell. Whenever I add text to the point that the `EditText` grows 1 line, the `ListView` scrolls to the top (and usually removes the `EditText` from view by doing so).

I found a few questions about this but they only seem to have "hacks" as answers and nothing that works for me.

[ListView scrolls to top when typing in multi-line EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479129/listview-scrolls-to-top-when-typing-in-multi-line-edittext)

[Listview with edittext - auto scroll on "next"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935312/listview-with-edittext-auto-scroll-on-next)

EDIT:
After a lot of research, I have found that it is because the editText is resizing, causing the ListView layout its subviews and then resetting to the top. I want to find a way for the EditText to grow while staying at the same place.

I tried this because of a suggestion I found online but, even though it keeps the `ListView` at the right height, it clears the focus from the `EditText` and I cannot seem to get it back with `requestFocus`.

```
private Stirng getTextWatcher(){
return new TextWatcher(){
@Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
@Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
@Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
listView.setSelection(index);
  }
 }
}
```

So what I would need is either:

1. Have a way for the `ListView` to not scroll automatically to the top when the subviews are being layed out again    or
2. A way to focus my `EditText` after having called `ListView.setSelected()`   or 3. Have another way to scroll the `ListView` that will not clear focus from the `EditText`.

For option

3. I have tried `scrollTo()` and `smoothScrollToPosition()`. `scrollTo` for some reason works but hides certain items from the `ListView` (they become invisible, not loaded). And `smoothScrollToPosition()` creates an animation where the `ListView` jumps to the top and then it brings the user back to the Item (and does it 2 or 3 times).

Comment: Can you post your code? Why don't these answers work for you?

Comment: @legendof post my code for what? the listview? It seems pretty standard to me. Nothing special. I don't do anything to it in java besides fill it, just in the XML. 
What I meant is that all of these are hacks and I want something elegant and efficient... not something like "scroll the listview every time a letter is added"

Comment: Can you show us the XML layout? The code for the listview, as well as it's parents. Is it inside a ScrollView by an chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As par my view if you want to take input from `ListView` item by using `EditText` then you should use `TextView` in place `EdiText` and by click of `TextView` you should open and Input Dialog with `EditText` that is more simple and good solution. handling of `EditText` focus  in `ListView` is vary difficult and you need to put extra `Listeners` for this.

**OR**

And if you have limited number of input box in your UI/UX then you can implement `EditText` with `CustomListView` by using `ScrollViews`.

Comment: I just tested your method. The second one worked flawlessly for me. 

What I did was use a linear layout inside of a scroll view and insert my views programatically in java. It works great and the scroll view stays at it's place when the edittext grows. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> ListView Scrolls to Top when EditText Grows

`ListView` has some known limitations related to child focus.

**Solution**

Why don't you try to use [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead of `ListView`?  Google introduced `RecyclerView` as the default recommended way of such UI. So custom `ListView` or hacks ore no more needed.

Comment: The same case also happens on RecyclerView. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765265/android-edittexts-container-recyclerview-auto-scroll-when-edittext-is-focused?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this attribute to your `ListView`:

```
android:transcriptMode="normal"
```

> This makes list automatically scroll to the bottom when a data set change notification is received and only if the last item is already visible on screen.

Read more here: [attr_android:transcriptMode | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode)